# ffmpeg doesnt wait for function to finish before running callback

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, asynccallback

I'm using ffmpeg to extract some frames from a video. Unfortunatley, node js does not wait for ffmpeg to finish the task before running the callback function How do I make sure, the task has finished before running the callback?

I have been struggling with this for hours, many thanks for any help

```
function callback() {

console.log("All done!")
}
async function main()
{
    try {
        var process = new ffmpeg("star_wars_film_scene.mp4");
        process.then(function (video) {
            video.fnExtractFrameToJPG("frames/", {
                every_n_frames : 1500
            }), callback()
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });
     } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.code);
        console.log(e.msg);
     }

    }
     


  main()
```

Comment: Pass just `callback` instead of `callback()`.  You are calling it and then passing the return value.  Instead, you need to pass the function reference itself without calling it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Simply removing the brackets has simply led to nothing being printed so I must be doing something wrong. I'm very new to coding and am a little unsure as to how I would implement such a solution, could you perhaps show me an example of how I could do this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what is going wrong with your installation.  I can say that this sample code, taken directly from the ffmpeg module page (with a slight tweak to add more error handling) works just fine for me. So, if you adapt your code to work like this and make sure that both the ffmpeg module and the ffmpeg executable are properly installed, it should work:

```
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

try {
    const process = new ffmpeg('full path to your video here');
    process.then(function(video) {
        // Callback mode
        video.fnExtractFrameToJPG('D:/temp', {
            frame_rate: 1,
            number: 5,
            file_name: 'my_frame_%t_%s'
        }, function(error, files) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Frames: ' + files);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
```

When I first ran this code on my system, I got an error because the ffmpeg executable (which was installed on my system) was not in my system path so when the ffmpeg module tried to run the ffmpeg executable, it didn't find it and it output an error message to that effect.  Once I fixed that to include it in my path, it worked as it is supposed to and captured 5 frames from the video I passed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    const process = new ffmpeg('star_wars_film_scene.mp4');
    process.then(function(video) {
        // Callback mode
        video.fnExtractFrameToJPG('helpers/frames/', {
            every_n_frames: 500
            
        }, function(error, files) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }
            console.log(‘all done’) 
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Houston, we have a problem')
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.